# Compress video and images before uploading to server

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, video, upload

Uploading images and videos to server together. User can select maximum of 5 images and 5 videos. So need to reduce the size of video and images before uploading. Please guide.
Below is what I am trying. Did something for images but no idea about video compression.

```
// images

if  let imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryImages.objectAtIndex(index) as! UIImage, 0.6) {              
    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData1, name: "image_path[]", fileName: strImgName, mimeType: "image/png")
}
```

// videos

```
let strVidName = "vid" + String(index) // + ".mov"

multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryVideos.objectAtIndex(index) as! NSData, name: "video_path[]", fileName: strVidName, mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can transform every original .mov file into an .mp4 compressed file before uploading the video to your server. Here is how in SWIFT 3:

First, create this function that encapsulates the compressing process. Please note that compressing files is an asynchronous task:

```
func compressVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {
                let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
                guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {
                    handler(nil)
                    return
                }

                exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
                exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4 //AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie (m4v)
                exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
                exportSession.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
                    handler(exportSession)
                }
            }
```

Now you can use compressVideo this way:

```
// Put in fileURL the URL of the original .mov video
let compressedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
let compressedFileData : Data? =  nil

// Encode to mp4
compressVideo(inputURL: fileURL, outputURL: compressedURL, handler: { (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?) -> Void in

    switch exportSession!.status {
        case .completed:

        print("Video compressed successfully")
        do {
            compressedFileData = try Data(contentsOf: exportSession!.outputURL!)
            // Call upload function here using compressedFileData
        } catch _ {
            print ("Error converting compressed file to Data")
        }

        default:
            print("Could not compress video")
    }
} )
```

Now you can upload compressedFileData as a multipart "image/mp4" file as usual

Comment: before i used this, the uploaded video was approx 10.5 MB, after i used it, still 10.5 MB approx. What can i do ?

Comment: Man you really helped me out :)

Comment: Question: what if the video is really, really big. Wouldn't that cause the app to crash if I try to create a variable (compressedFileData here)  that tries to store all that data? I was just wondering....

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad maybe your document already was mp4. This code just convert .mov to .mp4

Comment: @linus_hologram mp4 encoding will take long in that case but will work anyway. Providing encoding is async that should not be a problem. However in an old telephone enconding will be slow

Comment: This is for converting to mp4 not compression of a video. The answer should be more clear next time.